# AngularJs Custom directive not binding with "textarea"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I make a custom directives for prevent enter key. It work fine for only "input" element, but it's not binding on "textarea". 
here is my js

```
function inputFocus() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('keydown', function (event) {
                var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
                if (code === 13) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.$eval(attrs.inputFocus);
                    });
                     event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="UserName" maxlength="50" rows="2" 
          ng-model="UserName" tabindex="2" required>
</textarea>
```

Comment: show the text area

Comment: <textarea class="form-control" name="UserName" maxlength="50" rows="2" ng-model="UserName" tabindex="2" required></textarea>

Comment: where do you call the directive

Comment: what is your directive name and where you applied it?

Comment: I called in app Like "angular.module('apanelApp').directive('input', inputFocus)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake by asking your question :)
I give directives name by "input" so that it bind with all input elements. So, have to bind this also with "textarea" like

```
angular.module('apanelApp').directive('textarea', inputFocus);
```

Thanks to all for response.